# Difference between RPA and generalized RPA

Tags: condensed-matter, nuclear-physics, terminology

The [random phase approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_phase_approximation) (RPA) is an approximation method in condensed matter physics and in nuclear physics.

What is the difference between RPA and generalized RPA?

Comment: Do you have a specific example? The term RPA can be used in very different context, but usually it means resumming a given class of diagrams in a given channel.

Comment: @Adam I am interested in using RPA to compute correlation functions in general. Which diagrams should be summed? How is it different in generalized RPA?

Comment: There are no general rules for that, it completely depend on your problem. The RPA is just a resummation of a certain class of diagram. Knowing which class you have to resum to describe your problem is half the challenge. I can't help you without more specifics.